# How to create Desktop Notifications from Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications

I've noticed in the StackExchange chat, I can now enable Desktop Notifications (which I also use in Gmail and in Google Music). Now I've decided I want to be able to do that on my site. I did some Googling, but only found [info on Chrome Extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/dev/extensions/notifications.html). How do I make Desktop Notifications in my own site?

**EDIT**

In the Chrome console, I found the function `webkitNotifications.requestPermission()`, but calling it doesn't do anything. I expect it to show the Chrome top bar that asks "Would you like to enable desktop notifications for http://...?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a nice [Notification API tutorial at html5rocks.com](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/). Hope this helps!

FYI, the reason why `webkitNotifications.requestPermission()` didn't do anything when you call it is because

> this method should only be called while handling a user gesture, in
>   other circumstances it will have no effect

as stated in [Notification API Specs](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/desktop-notifications/api-specification). So you may need to implement this method in a user gesture *e.g* a mouse click, to make it effective:

```
<script>
function requestNotificationPermission()
{
    window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission();
}
</script>

<a onclick="requestNotificationPermission(); return false;" href="#">Request notifications permission</a>
```